# Setting local report hyperlink option to another local .rdlc report in c# Winforms application

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

From the screenshot window below, how can i specify a local(.rdlc) report in my applications reports folder? If i just enter the name of my Report, the hyper-link doesn't work, when you hover over the field value, there is completely no sign that a hyper-link exists.

But if i select Go to URL and enter **="http://www.mysite.co.ug/"** as the expression, it works.

I have a feeling am making an error in the way iam referencing my report path, i want to see an example in which the the option **Go to report** is selected and a local .rdlc report is specified.

[image]

How to do you refer to a local report in **Specify a Report area**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i just enter the name of my Report, the hyper-link doesn't work

You need to specify the fully-qualified name (including the namespace) of the .rdlc file in your project, and surround it with quotes - and since it's an expression it has to start with an equal sign so something like `="MyCompany.MySolution.MyProject.Reporting.MyReport.rdlc"` works (just tested it).