# Create linked local reports using ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am trying to use a ReportViewer control in local processing mode to create a linked report. So far, I am having no luck in specifying the second report in the action hyperlink options for the first report.

I found the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153429/setting-local-report-hyperlink-option-to-another-local-rdlc-report-in-c-sharp-w) which essentially outlines the exact issue I am having but I apparently still seem to miss something. Is there any way to retrieve the fully-qualified name of the .rdlc file?

If not, what would be the fully-qualified name given the following names:

> Company: Microsoft
>
> Assembly: ReportTest
>
> Solution: ReportTest
>
> Project: ReportTest
>
> Report 1: Report1.rdlc
>
> Report 2: Report2.rdlc
>
> Default namespace: ReportTest

Based on the answer provided in the other thread, I tried the following expression:

> ="Microsoft.ReportTest.ReportTest.ReportTest.Report2.rdlc"

but it does not generate any hyperlink. If I look at the `LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource` for the ReportViewer control, it is set to `ReportTest.Report1.rdlc` which I would expect to work for the hyperlink as well (`ReportTest.Report2.rdlc`), but it doesn't.

So, after trying pretty much any combination for the naming, I am hoping that someone could help me out here.

Any hints, pointers, suggestions etc. are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue of the Report Viewer 2010 SP1 control and can be rectified using an update. Further information can be found in the following [knowledge base article (KB 2549864)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549864).

After applying the fix, the linked report can simply be referenced using the default namespace followed by the report name. For the example above, the expression would be:

> ="ReportTest.Report2.rdlc"