# RDLC Reporting : How to display another rdlc report when I click on a row in a tablix?

Tags: c#, mysql, report, rdlc, windows-forms-designer

I am working on my project in c #, I need to display a report with in a report.

I am using MySQL as my database and I am creating the project on windows forms.

Let's say I have my parent report that contains the transaction id and other information of a customer record. Then what I want is that when the user clicks on a row/column in the table displayed on the report viewer, another report will show containing other details of the transaction and the items purchased by the customer.

I have tried searching about drillthrough in RDLC but I am not that lucky to find a tutorial that I can easily understand. I am just new to RDLC and in C#.

I hope someone could give me some idea, advice, help or even a tutorial on where/how to start. Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting local report hyperlink option to another local .rdlc report in c# Winforms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153429/setting-local-report-hyperlink-option-to-another-local-rdlc-report-in-c-sharp-w)

Comment: You could also use a SubReport here is a nice detailed tutorial on how to do that: [Walkthrough: Add a Subreport in local report in ReportViewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/01/03/walkthrough-add-a-subreport-in-local-report-in-reportviewer.aspx)